# Is there a way to force install chrome extensions across organisation?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have developed a chrome extension which I want to make the g-suite admins install for everyone in their org. Is that possible? If yes, is it a change I need to do in my extension or are there any specific steps for the admin to follow to install it for the org?

The documentation listed by google here seems to be specific only for chrome OS devices - https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6306504?hl=en

Comment: It applies to all systems.

Comment: The documentation you provided is the correct one for any OS.